# Java Proxy.newProxyInstance() throws type cast exception?

Tags: java, class, casting, proxy, instance

My following code tries to create a proxy-ed object that I expected to print "before" before calling "say()":

```
class Person2 {
    private String name;
    public Person2(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void say() {
        System.out.println("Person:" + name);
    }
}
class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private Object object;
    public MyHandler(Object o) {
        object = o;
    }
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable { //
        System.out.println("before");
        return method.invoke(object, args);
    }
}
public class TestProxy {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Person2 p = new Person2("myName");
        InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new MyHandler(p);
        Person2 obj = (Person2) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                p.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                p.getClass().getInterfaces(),
                invocationHandler);
        obj.say();
    }
}
```

But in fact it will throw out an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to Person2
at TestProxy.main
```

So where did I get wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't proxy classes with `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, only interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.lang.reflect.Proxy` can only be cast to `Interface` and also this line of code `p.getClass().getInterfaces()` would return empty interface because `Person2` doesn't implement any, 
so to fix this `Person2` need to implement an `Interface` :

```
public class Person2 implements IPerson{
    private String name;
    public Person2(String name) {
       this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public void say() {
       System.out.println("Person:" + name);
    }
}
```

Interface :

```
public interface IPerson {
   public void say();
}
```

then in main static method, can cast Proxy to Interface and invoke the method :

```
public class TestProxy {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
       Person2 p = new Person2("myName");
       InvocationHandler invocationHandler = new MyHandler(p);
       IPerson obj = (IPerson) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
             p.getClass().getClassLoader(),
             p.getClass().getInterfaces(),
             invocationHandler);
       obj.say();
    }
}
```